# Поэтапная смена блока в блоке при скролле страницы

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

Всем привет, есть код, который должен менять при скролле блок, но он не работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так. Спасибо.

```js
var func = function(e) {

    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#my-price-list').one('mousewheel', func);
    }, 500);
  
    var sec_1 = $(".section");
    let main__current = $('.main__current');
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
      if (main__current.is(':first-child')) {
        return;
      }
      main__current.removeClass("main__current").addClass("main__next")
      main__current.prev().addClass("main__current").removeClass("main__next main__previous")
  
    } else {
      if (main__current.is(':last-child')) {
        return;
      }
      main__current.removeClass("main__current").addClass("main__previous");
      main__current.next().addClass("main__current").removeClass("main__next main__previous")
    }
  
  
  };
  
  $('#my-price-list').one('mousewheel', func);
```

```html
       <div class="price-list" id="my-price-list">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="price-list-li">
                            <div class="price-list-li-div section section_1 main__section main__current">
                            <div class="price-list-upper-part">
                                <div class="price-list-li-text">
                                    <h3>Landing page</h3>
                                    <p>Разработка и дизайн креативного лендинга, который <br>привлекает внимание ваших клиентов и выделяет вас <br>среди конкурентов. </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="price-list-li-info">
                                    <div class="price-list-li-info-h">
                                        <h4 id="span">От 30 000 рублей </h4>
                                        <h4>Дизайн</h4>
                                        <h4>Под ключ</h4>
                                        <h4>От 10 дней</h4>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="portfolio-price-list">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="portfolio-pl-link">
                                        <p>Октябрь 2023</p>
                                        <img src="./Img and icon/Group2087.png">
                                        <a href=""><img src="./Img and icon/arrow45.svg" class="portfolio-price-list-arrow" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="portfolio-pl-link">
                                        <p>Октябрь 2023</p>
                                        <img src="./Img and icon/Group2087.png">
                                        <a href=""><img src="./Img and icon/arrow45.svg" class="portfolio-price-list-arrow" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="portfolio-pl-link">
                                        <p>Октябрь 2023</p>
                                        <img src="./Img and icon/Group2087.png">
                                        <a href=""><img src="./Img and icon/arrow45.svg" class="portfolio-price-list-arrow" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="price-list-li-link">
                                    <a href="#!" class="price-list-BTN">Получить консультацию <img src="./Img and icon/Arrow - Down 7.svg" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="price-list-li">
                            <div class="price-list-li-div section section_1 main__section main__current">
                            <div class="price-list-upper-part">
                                <div class="price-list-li-text">
                                    <h3>Landing page</h3>
                                    <p>Разработка и дизайн креативного лендинга, который <br>привлекает внимание ваших клиентов и выделяет вас <br>среди конкурентов. </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="price-list-li-info">
                                    <div class="price-list-li-info-h">
                                        <h4 id="span">От 30 000 рублей </h4>
                                        <h4>Дизайн</h4>
                                        <h4>Под ключ</h4>
                                        <h4>От 10 дней</h4>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="portfolio-price-list">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="portfolio-pl-link">
                                        <p>Октябрь 2023</p>
                                        <img src="./Img and icon/Group2087.png">
                                        <a href=""><img src="./Img and icon/arrow45.svg" class="portfolio-price-list-arrow" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="portfolio-pl-link">
                                        <p>Октябрь 2023</p>
                                        <img src="./Img and icon/Group2087.png">
                                        <a href=""><img src="./Img and icon/arrow45.svg" class="portfolio-price-list-arrow" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="portfolio-pl-link">
                                        <p>Октябрь 2023</p>
                                        <img src="./Img and icon/Group2087.png">
                                        <a href=""><img src="./Img and icon/arrow45.svg" class="portfolio-price-list-arrow" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="price-list-li-link">
                                    <a href="#!" class="price-list-BTN">Получить консультацию <img src="./Img and icon/Arrow - Down 7.svg" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="price-list-li">
                            <div class="price-list-li-div section section_1 main__section main__current">
                            <div class="price-list-upper-part">
                                <div class="price-list-li-text">
                                    <h3>Landing page</h3>
                                    <p>Разработка и дизайн креативного лендинга, который <br>привлекает внимание ваших клиентов и выделяет вас <br>среди конкурентов. </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="price-list-li-info">
                                    <div class="price-list-li-info-h">
                                        <h4 id="span">От 30 000 рублей </h4>
                                        <h4>Дизайн</h4>
                                        <h4>Под ключ</h4>
                                        <h4>От 10 дней</h4>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="portfolio-price-list">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="portfolio-pl-link">
                                        <p>Октябрь 2023</p>
                                        <img src="./Img and icon/Group2087.png">
                                        <a href=""><img src="./Img and icon/arrow45.svg" class="portfolio-price-list-arrow" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="portfolio-pl-link">
                                        <p>Октябрь 2023</p>
                                        <img src="./Img and icon/Group2087.png">
                                        <a href=""><img src="./Img and icon/arrow45.svg" class="portfolio-price-list-arrow" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="portfolio-pl-link">
                                        <p>Октябрь 2023</p>
                                        <img src="./Img and icon/Group2087.png">
                                        <a href=""><img src="./Img and icon/arrow45.svg" class="portfolio-price-list-arrow" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="price-list-li-link">
                                    <a href="#!" class="price-list-BTN">Получить консультацию <img src="./Img and icon/Arrow - Down 7.svg" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="price-list-li">
                            <div class="price-list-li-div section section_1 main__section main__current">
                            <div class="price-list-upper-part">
                                <div class="price-list-li-text">
                                    <h3>Landing page</h3>
                                    <p>Разработка и дизайн креативного лендинга, который <br>привлекает внимание ваших клиентов и выделяет вас <br>среди конкурентов. </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="price-list-li-info">
                                    <div class="price-list-li-info-h">
                                        <h4 id="span">От 30 000 рублей </h4>
                                        <h4>Дизайн</h4>
                                        <h4>Под ключ</h4>
                                        <h4>От 10 дней</h4>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="portfolio-price-list">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="portfolio-pl-link">
                                        <p>Октябрь 2023</p>
                                        <img src="./Img and icon/Group2087.png">
                                        <a href=""><img src="./Img and icon/arrow45.svg" class="portfolio-price-list-arrow" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="portfolio-pl-link">
                                        <p>Октябрь 2023</p>
                                        <img src="./Img and icon/Group2087.png">
                                        <a href=""><img src="./Img and icon/arrow45.svg" class="portfolio-price-list-arrow" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="portfolio-pl-link">
                                        <p>Октябрь 2023</p>
                                        <img src="./Img and icon/Group2087.png">
                                        <a href=""><img src="./Img and icon/arrow45.svg" class="portfolio-price-list-arrow" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="price-list-li-link">
                                    <a href="#!" class="price-list-BTN">Получить консультацию <img src="./Img and icon/Arrow - Down 7.svg" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </li>
          
                    </ul>
                </div>
```